Firefox doesn't prompt for smart card PIN
I have CAC authentication set up in Firefox according to the instructions militarycac.com. The card is recognized and authenticated successfully with both pcsc_scan and pkcs11-tool --login --test --pin=XXXX. When I go to a CAC-enabled web site in Firefox, I am prompted for a certificate, but when I select the certificate and click 'OK', I am never prompted for my PIN. It just hangs there for a few seconds until the website times out.
I added enable_pinpad=false to my opensc.conf, and confirmed it with opensc-tool --get-conf-entry app:default:enable_pinpad. Any idea why I'm not getting a prompt for my PIN?

Do you have the software that the DoD uses installed. I have used Firefox for over a decade without a problem, I absolutely know it works, the instructions on that website still work.

I'm not sure what software you're referring to, but I have all the pcsc packages listed on militarycac.com, plus opensc and all the listed certificates. I have also gotten CAC auth to work on Linux/Firefox before; this is the first time I've had the PIN prompt issure.

Same software installed on every DoD system nationwide (activclient) However, the switch you did, was still necessary. I know Firefox was compatible with it up until Firefox was removed on every DoD system.

Sorry, didn't mention that this is on Linux, so no Activclient.

What versions of FireFox, and OpenSC, and Linux?

Arch Linux, Firefox 132.0.1, and OpenSC 0.25-1.1 (from Arch Linux 'extra' repo)

Not a very satisfying answer, but I switched from OpenSC to CoolKey and the problem went away.

Here is what worked on DoD Systems before Firefox was removed.
